# On MacOS is there a way to change all Finder background images for icon view back to default?

Tags: finder, mojave, defaults, macos

Just upgraded to Mojave and am using dark mode but I realise that many of the Finder windows have a background set to a light background that does not match the new Mojave look.  I can go into the view options and change the background to Default and that works.  But how can I do this for all my folders at once.  I have lots of folders that are customised in this way.  Thanks in advance for your help!

[image]

Comment: Easiest way is probably deleting the finder preferences. I will add an answer shortly where that is located.

Comment: You mean the .DS_Store in each folder?  I tried that before but it does not work.  Went through the whole filesystem (below home) and deleted all of them with

```find ~ -name .DS_Store -delete```

but still not working

Comment: @GeorgeMcIntyre did you restart finder after you did that? Finder tends to “remember” DS_Store configurations after they’re deleted unless you relaunch finder.

Comment: @IronCraftMan yes I did.  But still didn't change